# Is it possible to change the color of a single bar when the bar plot is based on symbolic values?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I am beginner in LaTeX, trying to use it for industrial documents. I wonder if there is a way to change the color of only one bar of the plot below, ie "TestDetails", to illustrate it is a local macro and not a LaTeX keyword. I have been trying to experiment with point meta, but could not find a way.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents} 
\usepackage{pgfplots} 
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{width=.95\textwidth, compat=newest} 

\begin{document}

\begin{filecontents}{data.csv}
{Occurences}, {keyword}
215, item
159, SI
134, subsubsection
106, TestDetails
58, caption
\end{filecontents}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{data.csv}{\datatable}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
/pgf/number format/.cd,1000 sep={},
width=0.8\linewidth,height=6cm,
xbar,
xmin=30, xmax=250,
xtick=\empty,
enlarge x limits={value=0.1, upper},
enlarge y limits=0.1,
ytick=data, 
y dir=reverse,
xlabel= {},
y tick label style={major tick length=0pt},
yticklabels from table={\datatable}{[index]1},
nodes near coords, nodes near coords align=horizontal,
]
\addplot [draw,fill=blue!50]table[
y expr=\coordindex,
x index=0]{\datatable};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can't change the colour of an individual bar as such, but you can add a second `\addplot` where you filter out all bars but the one you want to highlight.

Here are two styles `discard if` and `discard if not`, which take two arguments: The name of the column in your table and the value that you want to highlight. Note that you'll need to supply the datafile itself to the `\addplot`, it doesn't work with a table created using `\pgfplotstableread`, and that you'll need to use `xtick={<list>}` instead of `xtick=data`, as otherwise your labels will be out of sync.

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{filecontents} 
\usepackage{pgfplots} 
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{width=.95\textwidth, compat=newest} 

\pgfplotsset{
    discard if/.style 2 args={
        x filter/.code={
            \edef\tempa{\thisrow{#1}}
            \edef\tempb{#2}
            \ifx\tempa\tempb
                \def\pgfmathresult{inf}
            \fi
        }
    },
    discard if not/.style 2 args={
        x filter/.code={
            \edef\tempa{\thisrow{#1}}
            \edef\tempb{#2}
            \ifx\tempa\tempb
            \else
                \def\pgfmathresult{inf}
            \fi
        }
    }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{filecontents}{data.csv}
{Occurences}, {keyword}
215, item
159, SI
134, subsubsection
106, TestDetails
58, caption
\end{filecontents}

\pgfplotstablegetrowsof{data.csv}
\edef\numberofrows{\pgfplotsretval}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
/pgf/number format/.cd,1000 sep={},
width=0.8\linewidth,height=6cm,
xbar,/pgf/bar shift=0pt,
xmin=0, xmax=250,
xtick=\empty,
enlarge x limits={value=0.1, upper},
enlarge y limits=0.1,
ytick={0,...,\numberofrows}, 
y dir=reverse,
xlabel= {},
y tick label style={major tick length=0pt},
yticklabels from table={data.csv}{[index]1},
nodes near coords, nodes near coords align=horizontal
]

\addplot [draw,fill=blue!50,discard if={keyword}{TestDetails}
] table [
    y expr=\coordindex,
    x index=0,col sep=comma
]{data.csv};

\addplot [draw,fill=orange,discard if not={keyword}{TestDetails}] table [
    y expr=\coordindex,
    x index=0,col sep=comma
]{data.csv};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 I’ve used this to make each bar a specific color. Maybe there’s an easier solution, but it worked for me.

Comment: @Jake  When I compile again  the code above, only the upper bar label (item) is created. I suspect that this change is linked to a more recent version of pgfplots, but I cannot find how to overcome this.

Comment: @Yves: For some reason, with the current version of PGFPlots, `\pgfplotsretval` doesn't retain the correct value for long enough. So instead of using `\pgfplotsretval` directly, you can store the number of rows in a macro using `\edef\numberofrows{\pgfplotsretval}` and then use `\numberofrows` in the `ytick` key. I've edited the answer.

Comment: @Jake And if I need to change the color of two bars?

Comment: @GeMir: You can add another `\addplot` with a `discard if not` statement.