# Different color for individual bar in bar chart & adding bar labels

Tags: pgfplots, color, labels, bar-chart

Please consider the following MWE.

There are three things I would like to do:

1. **Individual colouring** For the last element ("not rejected") I would like to fill the bar with another color (e.g. orange)
2. **Nicer x-axis label** The x-axis label "not rejected" ist too long for which reason I chose to rotate all x-axis labels via `x tick label style = {rotate=90}`. However, it does not look very nice. So maybe some has an idea. (What just came up my mind: I could replace "not rejected" with an "*" and include a note below the figure. No idea how that can be implemented.)
3. **Bar labels** The current y-values represent the absolute occurrence of each element. However, I would like to add the relative occurrence of each element on top of its bar. The information is provided in the last column of the table `EvalAbgelehntePP.dat`.

[image: bar chart]

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable} 

\begin{filecontents}{EvalAbgelehntePP.dat}
Wert    PP  HaeufigkeitAbs  HaeufigkeitRel
1   4   682 61.49684400360685
2   5   630 56.80793507664562
3   7   457 41.2082957619477
4   9   414 37.33092876465284
5   1   403 36.339044183949504
6   8   394 35.527502254283135
7   6   360 32.46167718665464
8   3   268 24.16591523895401
9   2   254 22.90351668169522
10  10  207 18.66546438232642
11  {not rejected}  226 20.378719567177637
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture} 
\begin{axis}[ 
    ybar,
    xtick={1,...,11},
    xticklabels from table = {EvalAbgelehntePP.dat}{PP},
    x tick label style = {rotate=90},
    xtick align=inside,
    xlabel={production programms},
    every axis x label/.style={at={(ticklabel cs:0.5)},anchor=near ticklabel},
    ylabel=occurrence,
    every axis y label/.style={at={(ticklabel cs:0.5)},rotate=90,anchor=near ticklabel}
] 


\addplot[ybar,fill=blue] table [ 
    x=Wert, 
    y=HaeufigkeitAbs,
] {EvalAbgelehntePP.dat} ;

\end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Found the following in the pgf-manual but how do I tell LaTeX to get the `nodes` data from the last column of `EvalAbgelehntePP.dat `? `nodes near coords, nodes near coords align={vertical},`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can adapt the approach from [Is it possible to change the color of a single bar when the bar plot is based on symbolic values?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58548/is-it-possible-to-change-the-color-of-a-single-bar-when-the-bar-plot-is-based-on/) for colouring a single bar in a different colour. I'm not sure what the best approach is for the single long label (what is `PP`?). What I did here is just rotate the long label, while leaving the others unrotated.

For adding the relative values, you have to tell PGFPlots that you're providing a `meta` value, by setting the key `point meta=explicit`, and then using `meta=<column name>` in the table options:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable} 

\pgfplotsset{
    discard if/.style 2 args={
        x filter/.code={
            \ifdim\thisrow{#1} pt=#2pt
                \def\pgfmathresult{inf}
            \fi
        }
    },
    discard if not/.style 2 args={
        x filter/.code={
            \ifdim\thisrow{#1} pt=#2pt
            \else
                \def\pgfmathresult{inf}
            \fi
        }
    }
}

\begin{filecontents}{EvalAbgelehntePP.dat}
Wert    PP  HaeufigkeitAbs  HaeufigkeitRel
1   4   682 61.49684400360685
2   5   630 56.80793507664562
3   7   457 41.2082957619477
4   9   414 37.33092876465284
5   1   403 36.339044183949504
6   8   394 35.527502254283135
7   6   360 32.46167718665464
8   3   268 24.16591523895401
9   2   254 22.90351668169522
10  10  207 18.66546438232642
11  {\rotatebox{90}{not rejected}}  226 20.378719567177637
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture} 
\begin{axis}[ 
    ybar,
    xtick={1,...,11},
    xticklabels from table = {EvalAbgelehntePP.dat}{PP},
    xtick align=inside,
    xlabel={production programms},
    every axis x label/.style={at={(ticklabel cs:0.5)},anchor=near ticklabel},
    ylabel=occurrence,
    every axis y label/.style={at={(ticklabel cs:0.5)},rotate=90,anchor=near ticklabel}
] 


\addplot[ybar, bar shift=0pt, fill=blue,
    discard if={Wert}{11},
    nodes near coords=\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfplotspointmeta}\%,
    every node near coord/.style={
        font=\scriptsize,
        /pgf/number format/precision=0
    },
    point meta=explicit] table [ 
    x=Wert, 
    y=HaeufigkeitAbs,
    meta=HaeufigkeitRel
] {EvalAbgelehntePP.dat} ;

\addplot[ybar, bar shift=0pt, fill=orange,
    discard if not={Wert}{11},
    nodes near coords=\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfplotspointmeta}\%,
    every node near coord/.style={
        font=\scriptsize,
        /pgf/number format/precision=0
    },
    point meta=explicit] table [ 
    x=Wert, 
    y=HaeufigkeitAbs,
    meta=HaeufigkeitRel
] {EvalAbgelehntePP.dat} ;

\end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: I saw the colour-approach but did not know how to adapt it to my problem. Many thanks!