# How to display the y-values of each bar in pgfplots bar chart above the bar?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, bar-chart, nodes-near-coords

I am using code from this thread.
link: [Making one bar in a bar-graph stand out pgfplots](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/116859/making-one-bar-in-a-bar-graph-stand-out-pgfplots/116861)

Everything is working fine but I want to display the y-values of each bar in pgfplots bar chart above the bar.

I tried 'nodes near coords' method but it is not working for the graph.

Please let me know how to put corresponding y-values above the bars.

Thank you.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? Not compiling? Not displaying properly?

Answer (score 2):

It works for me by simply adding the options `nodes near coords` and `enlargelimits` (the latter is just to make the axes bigger to account for the labels):
[image: nodes near coords]

Comment: Could you post the source for the image you've posted?