# create a stacked histogram with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I try to create a stacked histogram. Like this:
[image]

My data consists of classes (0-4) and a float value for each class.

I already have a histogram for all mean values. But I would like to color the bars according to the amount of classes in each bar.

What I have:

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}
% first number is a class (0-4), second float number is the mean of the data
\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
                1,0.177597344546
                1,0.18105947348
                1,0.177429493018
                2,0.244377481246
                4,0.185496836789
                0,0.180714004683
                4,0.187928321127
                3,0.188037364067
                4,0.187302774169
                3,0.188172520266
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
            ybar stacked,
            ymin=0,
        ]
        \addplot +[
            hist={
                bins=20,
            }   
        ] table [x, y, col sep=comma] {data.csv};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Does this help [is-it-possible-to-change-the-color-of-a-single-bar-when-the-bar-plot-is-based-on](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58548/is-it-possible-to-change-the-color-of-a-single-bar-when-the-bar-plot-is-based-on)?

Comment: You could always just plot the cumulative values on top of each other, starting from the final totals and working backward.  What data exactly do you want to plot?

Comment: @JohnKormylo an example of the data is included in the code above. The actual data looks the same, just much more. The approach you described would require to change the data presentation. Have to think about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution but I had to split my data. I created a data file for reach class (0-4) what can be easily done with grep. `grep 0, data.csv > mean0.csv`

If it is possible to add a condition when the data is loaded (load only the rows where x=0 for example), this step would be obsolete.

! xmin and xmax has to be defined so every histogram uses the same range.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}
% first number is a class (1-4), second float number is the mean of the data
\begin{filecontents*}{mean0.csv}
                0,0.180714004683
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{mean1.csv}
                1,0.177597344546
                1,0.18105947348
                1,0.177429493018
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{mean2.csv}
                2,0.244377481246
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{mean3.csv}
                3,0.188037364067
                3,0.188172520266
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{mean4.csv}
                4,0.185496836789
                4,0.187928321127
                4,0.187302774169
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[
                    ybar stacked,
                    ybar legend,
                    ylabel={\# traces},
                    xlabel={mean},
                    ymin=0,
                    xmin=0.17,
                    xmax=0.25,
                    legend style={at={(0.5,-0.20)},
                    anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
                ]
                \addplot +[hist={bins=20}]table [x, y, col sep=comma] {mean0.csv};
                \addplot +[hist={bins=20}]table [x, y, col sep=comma] {mean1.csv};
                \addplot +[hist={bins=20}]table [x, y, col sep=comma] {mean2.csv};
                \addplot +[hist={bins=20}]table [x, y, col sep=comma] {mean3.csv};
                \addplot +[hist={bins=20}]table [x, y, col sep=comma] {mean4.csv};
                \legend{pro1, pro2, pro3, pro4, pro5}
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{caption}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

The histogram looks like this now.

[image]

Comment: Does somebody know why the colors are not showing up in the legend ?

Comment: Actually, all you need to do to fix the legend entries is to add `ybar legend` in the `axis` environment.

Comment: Thank you. I already created a new version because of your previous comment. :D But now I have 2 solutions.

Comment: You're welcome. `:-)`

Answer (score 2):

Just for completeness. I created also another solution whereby I calculated the histogram bins beforehand with a python script.

Before my data looked like this:

```
<class, mean_value>    
1,0.177597344546
1,0.18105947348
1,0.177429493018
...
```

After the python script data is like this:

```
<bin_value   class1  class2 class3 class4 class5>
0.177093 471 882 0 0 0
0.180632 538 127 0 135 0
0.184171 0 0 0 691 556
....
```

The final latex example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}
\begin{filecontents*}{data2.csv}
0.177093 471 882 0 0 0
0.180632 538 127 0 135 0
0.184171 0 0 0 691 556
0.187710 0 0 0 183 453
0.191249 0 0 0 0 0
0.194788 0 0 0 0 0
0.198327 0 0 0 0 0
0.201866 0 0 0 0 0
0.205405 0 0 0 0 0
0.208944 0 0 0 0 0
0.212483 0 0 0 0 0
0.216022 0 0 0 0 0
0.219561 0 0 0 0 0
0.223100 0 0 0 0 0
0.226639 0 0 0 0 0
0.230178 0 0 0 0 0
0.233717 0 0 0 0 0
0.237256 0 0 0 0 0
0.240795 0 0 124 0 0
0.244334 0 0 885 0 0
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{document}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[
                    ybar stacked,
                    ylabel={\# traces},
                    xlabel={mean},
                    ymin=0,
                    legend style={at={(0.5,-0.20)},
                    anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
                ]  
                \addplot +[ybar]table [x index=0,y index=1] {data2.csv};
                \addplot +[ybar]table [x index=0,y index=2] {data2.csv};
                \addplot +[ybar]table [x index=0,y index=3] {data2.csv};
                \addplot +[ybar]table [x index=0,y index=4] {data2.csv};
                \addplot +[ybar]table [x index=0,y index=5] {data2.csv};
                \legend{pro1, pro2, pro3, pro4, pro5}
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The resulting graphs is the same as above.

If somebody requests, I can also post the python script.