# How to read a specific portion of a data file in pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have a data file which contains all the experiments that have been conducted for different cases. Is it possible in `pgfplots` to only read specific portion of the file and plot the results?

Let's say the data file, named `mydata.dat`, looks like the following:

```
case    var1    var2    var3
1   0.10    0.25    10.00
1   0.20    0.35    25.00
1   0.30    0.45    40.00
1   0.40    0.55    55.00
1   0.50    0.65    70.00
1   0.60    0.75    85.00
2   1.00    0.50    55.00
2   2.00    0.50    55.00
2   3.00    0.50    55.00
2   4.00    0.50    55.00
2   5.00    0.50    55.00
2   6.00    0.50    55.00
2   7.00    0.50    55.00
2   8.00    0.50    55.00
2   9.00    0.50    55.00
3   10.00   1.00    22.50
3   20.00   2.00    22.50
3   30.00   3.00    22.60
3   40.00   4.00    22.70
3   50.00   5.00    22.65
4   100.00  10.00   135.00
4   200.00  20.00   140.00
4   300.00  30.00   137.00
4   400.00  40.00   144.00
4   500.00  50.00   141.00
4   600.00  60.00   136.00
4   700.00  70.00   136.00
```

How can I read the file using `pgfplot` and for example plot the data only for `case=3` which are:

```
3   10.00   1.00    22.50
3   20.00   2.00    22.50
3   30.00   3.00    22.60
3   40.00   4.00    22.70
3   50.00   5.00    22.65
```

How can I modify the following code to be able to obtain the results I am looking for?

```
\documentclass[crop=true,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[%
        axis on top,
        width = 4cm,
        height = 4cm,
        scale only axis,           
    ]
    \addplot
        table [%
        col sep=tab, %
        x=var1, y=var2,] %
        {mydata.dat};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: As you've noted yourself, filtering is probably the way to go, but I do notice that your `var1` column here has ranges that suggest you could simple do `xmax`/`xmin` setting.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found the solution by adding the following code, taken from [Is it possible to change the color of a single bar when the bar plot is based on symbolic values?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58548/is-it-possible-to-change-the-color-of-a-single-bar-when-the-bar-plot-is-based-on)

```
\pgfplotsset{
    discard if not/.style 2 args={
        x filter/.code={
            \edef\tempa{\thisrow{#1}}
            \edef\tempb{#2}
            \ifx\tempa\tempb
            \else
                \def\pgfmathresult{inf}
            \fi
        }
    }
}
```

It defines a filter such that every row of the given column name (here parameterized by the first input `#1`) is compared with the value given by the input parameter `#2` and if the result is false then the row value is set to infinity, otherwise the value of `\pgfmathresult` is passed through. Same functionality can also be achieved via PGF math comparison

```
\pgfplotsset{
    discard if not/.style 2 args={
        x filter/.code={%
            \let\tempa=\pgfmathresult% Save the original value
            \pgfmathparse{\thisrow{#1}==#2?\tempa:"inf"}% Test against #2
        }
    }
}
```

This solution relies on the `unbounded coords=discard` setting such that whenever the value `inf` is found that coordinate set is discarded.

Here is the working code:

```
\documentclass[crop=true,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}


\begin{document}

\pgfplotsset{
    discard if not/.style 2 args={
        x filter/.code={
            \edef\tempa{\thisrow{#1}}
            \edef\tempb{#2}
            \ifx\tempa\tempb
            \else
                \def\pgfmathresult{inf}
            \fi
        }
    }
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
      title={{\bfseries Plot for case3}},
      xlabel={var1},
      ylabel={var2}]
    \addplot+[only marks, discard if not={case}{3}] table[x=var1, y=var2]
      {mydata.dat};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Added some comments.

Comment: @percusse: Thank you. Does `discard if not/.style 2 args` define the command name as `discard if not` and specifies that this command needs two arguments? I would be thankful if you could also let me know the role of `/.style`?

Comment: Yes. You can find those details in the TikZ manual in the section of `pgfkeys`

Comment: Visit http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/178652/23594 for the interpretation of the added `pgfplotsset`.

Comment: @A2009: One note about the statement that "same functionality can also be achieved via PGF math comparison": the PGF math comparison can be used for numerical comparisons, where you want `1.00 == 1` to return True. The approach with `\ifx` is used for comparing symbolic (i.e. text) coordinates. If I remember correctly, the code was first used in [http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58548/is-it-possible-to-change-the-color-of-a-single-bar-when-the-bar-plot-is-based-on](Is it possible to change the color of a single bar when the bar plot is based on symbolic values?).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a shorter alternative:

```
\addplot table [col sep=tab, x=var1, %
                y expr={\thisrow{var2} / (\thisrow{case} == 3)}] %
      {mydata.dat};
```

It is based on operator `==` which returns either `1` or `0`. When it returns `0`, the division gives infinity and the corresponding row is not plotted.

Same logic can be used with `<` and `>` operators to plot specific range of values.