# Question on interpretation of a pgfplotsset

Tags: pgfplots

I am trying to understand the following code:

```
\pgfplotsset{
    discard if not/.style 2 args={
        x filter/.code={
            \edef\tempa{\thisrow{#1}}
            \edef\tempb{#2}
            \ifx\tempa\tempb
            \else
                \def\pgfmathresult{inf}
            \fi
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my understanding after reading the manual:

1. `\pgfplotsset` is used to set document-wise style.
2. `discard if not/.style 2 args` defines a style named `discard if not` in the namespace `/pgfplots` and takes two arguments: `#1` and `#2`.
3. `x filter/.code` is used to change the behavior of the PGFPLOTS regarding coordinate filtering. Here, we are saying to use `x filter` for coordinate filtering based on a single coordinate. `.code` is similar to TeX command: `\newcommand`. `x filter` gets an input coordinate as `#1` and applies filtering and finally writes the results into the macro `\pgfmathresult`. If we set `\pgfmathresult` to `inf` by `\pgfmathresults{inf}` this means the coordinate can be discarded (if `unbounded coords=discard` is set).
4. `\thisrow{#1}` returns the active row in `#1` column. In other words, `\thisrow{#1}` = table(active row,column=`#1`).
5. `\tempa{\thisrow{#1}}` defines a macro named `tempa` which has a value of the currently active table row in the designated column, `\tempa` = table(active row,column=`#1`).
6. `\edef` refers to expanded definition. It expands the macro to evaluate its value.
7. `\edef\tempa{\thisrow{#1}}` evaluate the macro and assigns the value of the active row in the designated column to `tempa`.
8. `\edef\tempb{#2}` assigns the value of the second argument to macro `tempb`.
9. `\ifx`: I couldn't find this in the manual but I am assuming that `\ifx\tempa\tempb` is equivalent to logical condition: `\tempa == \tempb`. Maybe we have `\ify`?
10. `\pgfmathresult{inf}`: up to this moment `\pgfmathresult` has the value of the x coordinate and setting it to `inf` discards the coordinate if `unbounded coords=discard` has been set.
11. `\def\pgfmathresult{inf}` I couldn't find what exactly `\def` does but I assume it sets the value of `\pgfmathresult` to `inf` which can refer to discarding.

So, `discard if not` is a name of a style that when is called applies a coordinate discarding based on two input arguments.

I would be thankful if someone could correct me if I have not understood it correctly or give me a better interpretation.

Comment: Might be interesting: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12668/where-do-i-start-latex-programming/27589#27589

Comment: Wonderful! I have been looking for such a documentation forever. Thanks for sharing it in here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is indeed correct but requires a few nuances to be clarified;

1. `\pgfplotsset` is used to set `key=value` pairs specific to the `pgfplots` key family. It can be seen in the pgfkeys section in the TikZ manual. The main idea to use this is to avoid every time entering `/pgfplots/` prefix to each key to be set. TikZ has `\tikzset`, pgfplotstable has `\pgfplotstableset` etc. Hence it sets the namespace automatically to `pgfplots`
2. `discard if not/.style 2 args` defines a style named `discard if not` in the namespace `/pgfplots/` and takes two arguments: `#1` and `#2`. **Yes and those inputs `#1` and `#2` are still available inside this style**
3. `x filter/.code` is used to change the behavior of the PGFPLOTS regarding coordinate filtering. Here, we are saying to use `x filter` for coordinate filtering based on a single coordinate. `.code` is a handler which executes a piece of code instead of a style setting up a value or other styles. <strike>similar to TeX command: `\newcommand`</strike>.

   `x filter` holds the code to evaluate the current value and we can alter the value of `\pgfmathresult` . We use the previously defined `#1` and `#2` to assess the values. If we set `\pgfmathresult` to `inf` by `\pgfmathresults{inf}` this means the coordinate can be discarded (`unbounded coords=discard` is set).
4. `\thisrow{#1}` returns the active row in `#1` column. In other words, `\thisrow{#1}` = table(active row,column=`#1`). **Yes**
5. `\edef\tempa{\thisrow{#1}}` defines a macro named `tempa` which has the **expanded** value of the currently active table row in the designated column, `\tempa` = table(active row,column=`#1`).
6. `\edef` refers to expanded definition. It expands the macro to evaluate its value. The difference is that the value of `\thisrow{#1}` is used immediately upon definition. If `\def` is used it will wait unexpanded until it is used and use the last value.
7. `\edef\tempa{\thisrow{#1}}` evaluate the macro and assigns the value of the active row in the designated column to `tempa`.**The same**
8. `\edef\tempb{#2}` assigns the value of the second argument to macro `tempb`.
9. `\ifx`: I couldn't find this in the manual but I am assuming that `\ifx\tempa\tempb` is equivalent to logical condition. It is difficult to explain all the nuances here but for simplicity it is an expanded conditional. It expands the macros in the input stream until it finds two *things* that cannot be expanded further and compares them.
10. `\pgfmathresult{inf}`: up to this moment `\pgfmathresult` has the value of the x coordinate and setting it to `inf` discards the coordinate if `unbounded coords=discard` has been set.
11. `\def\pgfmathresult{inf}` I couldn't find what exactly `\def` does but I assume it sets the value of `\pgfmathresult` to `inf` which can refer to discarding.**See `\edef` above** These are TeX primitives and explained elsewhere.

So, `discard if not` is a name of a style that when is called applies a **x** coordinate filter based on two input arguments.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you understood almost all of the code correctly.

If I remember correctly, that code was first used in the answer to [Is it possible to change the color of a single bar when the bar plot is based on symbolic values?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58548/is-it-possible-to-change-the-color-of-a-single-bar-when-the-bar-plot-is-based-on). It's used for filtering symbolic coordinates (not numerical ones). That explains the use of `\ifx`: That macro compares two eXpanded arguments (the "x" doesn't refer to the x-axis, but to eXpansion). If they expand to the same string, some code is executed.

`\def\pgfmathresult{inf}` redefines the macro `\pgfmathresult` to evaluate to `inf`.