# Place node at local maxima or minima of graph

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, pgfplotstable, pgfmath

**Though there is an upvoted answer - the question is NOT answered.**

---

It turned out, that without `smooth` the resulting figure gets produced and looks alright, but the **error remains**. How to get rid of the error?

---

This is a direct follow up question of [**Jake's answer**](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/46182/36835), which works perfectly for **global maxima and minima**.

[image]

(I changed his code a little to get a custom node description, and apply it to my case with pgfplotstable and groupplot)

But how about **local maxima and minima**? How to get the maximum of the second peak?

---

**What I tried:**

It seemend an easy solution to me to introduce a second plot (maybe invisible) and add a domain restriction:

```
\addplot[blue,mark max=A, restrict expr to domain = {x}{3000:500000}] table[x expr= \thisrowno{0}, y expr= \thisrowno{1} ] from \myTable;
```

However I got the following error:

```
Package PGF Math Error: Could not parse input '' as a floating point number, sorry. The unreadable part was near ''. (in 'x '). ...= {x}{3000:500000},mark max=A]table{sample.table};
```

and the following image:

[image]

**So it looks alright, but how to get rid of the error?**

Any solutions? Thank you!

---

Unfortunately the [**solution provided by salim bou**](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/275672/36835) does not work with pfgplotstable and the way I load data, which is a must.

---

### Updated MWE with pgfplotstable

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}

\makeatletter
\pgfplotsset{
    compat=1.12,
    /tikz/max node/.style={
        anchor=south,
    },
    /tikz/min node/.style={
        anchor=north,
        name=minimum
    },
    mark min/.style={
        point meta rel=per plot,
        visualization depends on={x \as \xvalue},
        scatter/@pre marker code/.code={%
            \ifx\pgfplotspointmeta\pgfplots@metamin
            \def\markopts{}%
            \coordinate (minimum);
            \node[name=#1] {};%
            \else
            \def\markopts{mark=none}
            \fi
            \expandafter\scope\expandafter[\markopts,every node near coord/.style=green]
        },%
        scatter/@post marker code/.code={%
            \endscope
        },
        scatter,
    },
    mark min/.default={below},
    mark max/.style={
        point meta rel=per plot,
        visualization depends on={x \as \xvalue},
        scatter/@pre marker code/.code={%
            \ifx\pgfplotspointmeta\pgfplots@metamax
            \def\markopts{}%
            \coordinate (maximum);
            \node[name=#1] {};%
            \else
            \def\markopts{mark=none}
            \fi
            \expandafter\scope\expandafter[\markopts]
        },%
        scatter/@post marker code/.code={%
            \endscope
        },
        scatter
    },
    mark max/.default={above},
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{sample.table}
    x y
    1 0.2
    10 0.1
    200 0.4
    3000 -0.3
    40000 0.3
    500000 -0.2
\end{filecontents*}


\pgfplotsset{
    discard if/.style n args={3}{
        x filter/.code={
            \edef\tempa{\thisrowno{#1}}
            \edef\tempb{#2}
            \edef\tempc{#3}
            \ifnum\tempa>\tempb
            \ifnum\tempa<\tempc
            \else
            \def\pgfmathresult{inf}
            \fi
            \else
            \def\pgfmathresult{inf}
            \fi
        }
    }
}


\begin{document}
    
    \begin{figure}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        
        \pgfplotstableread[skip first n=1]{sample.table}\myTable
        
        \begin{groupplot}[
        group style={group name=group,
            group size=1 by 2,
            x descriptions at=edge bottom,
            y descriptions at=edge left,
            vertical sep=0.5cm,
        }]
        
        \nextgroupplot[xmode=log,xlabel={X},ylabel={Y},]
        
        \addplot[blue,mark max=A] table[x expr= \thisrowno{0}, y expr= \thisrowno{1} ] from \myTable;
        \addplot[red,mark max=B, restrict expr to domain = {x}{3000:500000}] table[x expr= \thisrowno{0}, y expr= \thisrowno{1} ] from \myTable;
        \end{groupplot}
        
        \node[above] at (A) {Hello World!};
        \node[above] at (B) {Hello World!};
        
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}
    
\end{document}
```

I assume the reason is the use of `\thisrow` in the `discard if`-style. However `table[x index={0}, y index={1}]` does not work neither.

---

### Old MWE (works with salim bou's answer)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\makeatletter
\pgfplotsset{
    compat=1.12,
    /tikz/max node/.style={
        anchor=south,
    },
    /tikz/min node/.style={
        anchor=north,
        name=minimum
    },
    mark min/.style={
        point meta rel=per plot,
        visualization depends on={x \as \xvalue},
        scatter/@pre marker code/.code={%
            \ifx\pgfplotspointmeta\pgfplots@metamin
            \def\markopts{}%
            \coordinate (minimum);
            \node[name=#1] {};%
            \else
            \def\markopts{mark=none}
            \fi
            \expandafter\scope\expandafter[\markopts,every node near coord/.style=green]
        },%
        scatter/@post marker code/.code={%
            \endscope
        },
        scatter,
    },
    mark min/.default={below},
    mark max/.style={
        point meta rel=per plot,
        visualization depends on={x \as \xvalue},
        scatter/@pre marker code/.code={%
            \ifx\pgfplotspointmeta\pgfplots@metamax
            \def\markopts{}%
            \coordinate (maximum);
            \node[name=#1] {};%
            \else
            \def\markopts{mark=none}
            \fi
            \expandafter\scope\expandafter[\markopts]
        },%
        scatter/@post marker code/.code={%
            \endscope
        },
        scatter
    },
    mark max/.default={above},
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{sample.table}
    x y
    1 0.2
    10 0.1
    20 0.4
    30 -0.3
    40 0.3
    50 -0.2
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{figure}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
        xlabel={X},
        ylabel={Y},
        xmax=50,
        xmin=0,
        ymax=.5,
        ymin=-.5,
        width=15cm,
        height=5cm,
        ]
        \addplot[blue,smooth,mark max=A]table{sample.table};
        % \addplot[blue,smooth, restrict expr to domain = {x}{30:45},mark max=A]table{sample.table};
        \end{axis}
        
        \node[above] at (A) {Hello World!};
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{Caption}
    \end{figure}
    
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

Referencing [how to read a specific portion of a data file in pgfplots](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/178629/how-to-read-a-specific-portion-of-a-data-file-in-pgfplots), you can create a test like this

```
\pgfplotsset{
    discard if/.style n args={3}{
        x filter/.code={
            \edef\tempa{\thisrow{#1}}
            \edef\tempb{#2}
            \edef\tempc{#3}
            \ifnum\tempa>\tempb
              \ifnum\tempa<\tempc
              \else
              \def\pgfmathresult{inf}
              \fi
            \else
              \def\pgfmathresult{inf}
            \fi
        }
    }
}
```

Which compare content for every row of the given column name with values defined in the `#2` and `#3` parameters, if the first value is trapped between the two other  the value is `\pgfmathresult` otherwise  the row value is set to infinity.

---

**Code**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\makeatletter
\pgfplotsset{
    compat=1.12,
    /tikz/max node/.style={
        anchor=south,
    },
    /tikz/min node/.style={
        anchor=north,
        name=minimum
    },
    mark min/.style={
        point meta rel=per plot,
        visualization depends on={x \as \xvalue},
        scatter/@pre marker code/.code={%
            \ifx\pgfplotspointmeta\pgfplots@metamin
            \def\markopts{}%
            \coordinate (minimum);
            \node[name=#1] {};%
            \else
            \def\markopts{mark=none}
            \fi
            \expandafter\scope\expandafter[\markopts,every node near coord/.style=green]
        },%
        scatter/@post marker code/.code={%
            \endscope
        },
        scatter,
    },
    mark min/.default={below},
    mark max/.style={
        point meta rel=per plot,
        visualization depends on={x \as \xvalue},
        scatter/@pre marker code/.code={%
            \ifx\pgfplotspointmeta\pgfplots@metamax
            \def\markopts{}%
            \coordinate (maximum);
            \node[name=#1] {};%
            \else
            \def\markopts{mark=none}
            \fi
            \expandafter\scope\expandafter[\markopts]
        },%
        scatter/@post marker code/.code={%
            \endscope
        },
        scatter
    },
    mark max/.default={above},
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{sample.table}
    x y
    1 0.2
    10 0.1
    20 0.4
    30 -0.3
    40 0.3
    50 -0.2
\end{filecontents*}


\pgfplotsset{
    discard if/.style n args={3}{
        x filter/.code={
            \edef\tempa{\thisrow{#1}}
            \edef\tempb{#2}
            \edef\tempc{#3}
            \ifnum\tempa>\tempb
              \ifnum\tempa<\tempc
              \else
              \def\pgfmathresult{inf}
              \fi
            \else
              \def\pgfmathresult{inf}
            \fi
        }
    }
}


\begin{document}

    \begin{figure}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
        xlabel={X},
        ylabel={Y},
        xmax=50,
        xmin=0,
        ymax=.5,
        ymin=-.5,
        width=15cm,
        height=5cm,
        ]
        \addplot[blue,smooth,mark max=A]table{sample.table};
        \addplot[blue,smooth, discard if={x}{30}{45},mark max=B,red,draw=none]table{sample.table};
        \end{axis}

        \node[above] at (A) {Hello World!};
        \node[above] at (B) {Hello World!};
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{Caption}
    \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

**Result**

[image]

Comment: aargh, always the same with these minimal examples, they are always to minimal. Your solution seems to be incompatible with my way of achieving the data (with pgfplotstable), probably because the `discard if` style also uses `thisrow{#1}`. Do you see a way around this?

Comment: Tray to update `pgfplots` the last version `1.12.1`.

Comment: I have the latest version.

Comment: Here the code with [overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/read/zpnzbxrtgrzj), no problem.

Comment: Yes your code works as it is, but it doesn't if you use `pgfplotstable`. That's why I was asking if you could modify your solution, so it would work for my modified MWE? Thank you!