# pgfplots: Coloring a Single Column in a Histogram Differently

Tags: pgfplots

I have a huge data file and want to visualize the data using histograms. I would like to color a single columns differently than the rest. Here's an example from the documentation (Section 5.11.2 Histograms):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.statistics}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
ybar interval,
xticklabel=
\pgfmathprintnumber\tick--\pgfmathprintnumber\nexttick
]
\addplot+[hist={bins=3}]
table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
data\\
1\\ 2\\ 1\\ 5\\ 4\\ 10\\
7\\ 10\\ 9\\ 8\\ 9\\ 9\\
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I get:

[image]

Now I want manually decide which column to color differently like (done with Paint...):

[image]

Has anyone an idea? For normal plots one would just put two plots in one diagram. But here I do not know how to do it.

---

This is maybe [related](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58548/is-it-possible-to-change-the-color-of-a-single-bar-when-the-bar-plot-is-based-on/).

Comment: I do not have a solution, but I am just curious as to how you want to choose the bar to plot with a different colour. Are you looking for a function that takes a bin number and colour as parameters?

Comment: Good point! A function with number and parameter would be perfect. Or maybe I'll have to draw two diagrams on top of each other somehow (two addplot). But honestly I don't know. Maybe I wish too much.

Comment: In common graphs, I usually use two `axis` environments with the same specifications (the graphs are overlapping). But this task looks more complicated.

Comment: My thoughts exactly :)

Comment: I'm thinking of a different way: to do computations in Lua/externally and plot a common bar type graph.

Comment: @Malipivo: Good idea - will you post an example?

Comment: I'd love to, but I can't work on it these days. I'll keep your task in mind until you accept some answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One can certainly make macros to automatize the process :

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.statistics}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
ybar interval,
xticklabel=
\pgfmathprintnumber\tick--\pgfmathprintnumber\nexttick
]
\addplot+[hist={bins=3}]
table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
data\\
1\\ 2\\ 1\\ 5\\ 4\\ 10\\
7\\ 10\\ 9\\ 8\\ 9\\ 9\\
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}


\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ybar interval,
    xtick=data,
    xticklabel interval boundaries,
    ]
\addplot+[hist={bins=3}]
table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
data\\
1\\ 2\\ 1\\ 5\\ 4\\ 10\\
7\\ 10\\ 9\\ 8\\ 9\\ 9\\
};
\end{axis}

\begin{axis}[ybar interval,
    ticklabel style={opacity=0},
    hist/data min={1},
    hist/data max={4}
    ]

% 1-4 4-7 7-10

\addplot+[hist={bins=1,
    data filter/.code={%
    \pgfmathparse{#1<4 ? #1 : "nan"}}
    }
]
table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
data\\
1\\ 2\\ 1\\ 5\\ 4\\ 10\\
7\\ 10\\ 9\\ 8\\ 9\\ 9\\
};

\addplot+[hist={bins=1,
    data filter/.code={%
    \pgfmathparse{and(#1>=4,#1<7) ? #1 : "nan"}},
    },
style={draw=blue,fill=red!35}
]
table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
data\\
1\\ 2\\ 1\\ 5\\ 4\\ 10\\
7\\ 10\\ 9\\ 8\\ 9\\ 9\\
};

\pgfplotsset{cycle list shift=-2}
\addplot+[hist={bins=1,
    data filter/.code={%
    \pgfmathparse{#1>=7 ? #1 : "nan"}}
    }
]
table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
data\\
1\\ 2\\ 1\\ 5\\ 4\\ 10\\
7\\ 10\\ 9\\ 8\\ 9\\ 9\\
};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Great - I will have a look at it on the weekend. I don't get it yet.

Comment: There is an extra `}` on line 41 of the code example. As a result, the document does not compile cleanly.

Comment: Ok, edits after corrections ... still artefacts. Thank you.