# pgfplots, how to select only certain classes to plot

Tags: pgfplots

I started to use this fantastic package `pgfplots`, and I would need a little help.
In [this example taken from the manual](http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/pgfplots.pdf) (page 106)

```
\begin{tikzpicture} \begin{axis}[scatter/classes={
a={mark=square*,blue},%
b={mark=triangle*,red},%
c={mark=o,draw=black}}]
\addplot[scatter,only marks,
    scatter src=explicit symbolic]
    coordinates {
        (0.1,0.15)  [a]
        (0.45,0.27) [c]
        (0.02,0.17) [a]
        (0.06,0.1)  [a]
        (0.9,0.5)   [b]
        (0.5,0.3)   [c]
        (0.85,0.52) [b]
        (0.12,0.05) [a]
        (0.73,0.45) [b]
        (0.53,0.25) [c]
        (0.76,0.5)  [b]
        (0.55,0.32) [c]};
\end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}
```

three scatter classes are created, a, b, and c, each consisting of a few points. Each has separate mark formatting options and legend entry, which is a great feature. But I haven't found any way to turn certain scatter classes "off".

Is there any easy trick to plot only class "a" or "b"? In principle I'd like to use this meta-data as a selection or filter on the data. It would be extremely useful.

Not naming the scatter class would not help, all the points are still there but unformatted, and I could not find another solution in a reasonable time. If it's not possible with the classes, can such filtering be done in any other way?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For applications like these, I would go with `\addplot ... table` instead of `\addplot ... coordinates`. That makes it easier to access coordinate attributes, and it also makes it much easier to use data from external applications in PGFPlots.

If you provide the data as a table, you can use the `discard if={<column name>}{<value>}` and `discard if not` styles from [Is it possible to change the color of a single bar when the bar plot is based on symbolic values?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58548/is-it-possible-to-change-the-color-of-a-single-bar-when-the-bar-plot-is-based-on) for filtering your data:

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}


\begin{document}

\pgfplotsset{
    discard if/.style 2 args={
        x filter/.code={
            \edef\tempa{\thisrow{#1}}
            \edef\tempb{#2}
            \ifx\tempa\tempb
                \def\pgfmathresult{inf}
            \fi
        }
    },
    discard if not/.style 2 args={
        x filter/.code={
            \edef\tempa{\thisrow{#1}}
            \edef\tempb{#2}
            \ifx\tempa\tempb
            \else
                \def\pgfmathresult{inf}
            \fi
        }
    }
}


\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    scatter/classes={
        a={mark=square*,blue},%
        b={mark=triangle*,red},%
        c={mark=o,draw=black}
    }
]
\addplot[scatter,only marks,
    scatter src=explicit symbolic,
    discard if={class}{a}
]
    table [meta index=2]{
        x       y       class
        0.1     0.15    a
        0.45    0.27    c
        0.02    0.17    a
        0.06    0.1     a
        0.9     0.5     b
        0.5     0.3     c
        0.85    0.52    b
        0.12    0.05    a
        0.73    0.45    b
        0.53    0.25    c
        0.76    0.5     b
        0.55    0.32    c
       };
\end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This works great, thanks! I'm using a large table actually (a .csv file), and I tested it. The legend entries of course have to be removed manually, but otherwise it's great. I wish your code was included in the package :)