Filtering a CSV using \pgfplotstableread
I have ONE CSV, and then, at a later stage, I need to plot a number of graphs from this CSV.  I want to avoid having to load too many CSVs, so I need to filter data based on the loaded CSV.
I am reading data from a CSV file using
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{data.csv}{\datatable}

Then I plot using
\myplot{\datatable}

I need to filter the data by column named 'chart' which contains text data.  So for example filter \datatable using something which in SQL would look like
SELECT * FROM DATA.CSV WHERE chart = 'AP-0X1X'

Here is an example of my files:
main.tex
\documentclass{article}

% Include the template file
\input{plot_template}

\begin{document}

% Read data from an external CSV file
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{data3.csv}{\datatable}
% Use the template with the data, y-tick interval, and y-axis label
\myplot{\datatable}{1}{AR}{1}

\end{document}

plot_template.tex
\ProvidesFile{plot_template.tex}[2024/07/04 Plot template]

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

% Define the TikZ template as a macro
\newcommand{\myplot}[4]{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=#4]
      \begin{axis} [
          width  = 0.9*\textwidth,
          height = 8cm,
          symbolic x coords={4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14},
          minor ytick={#2, 2*#2, 3*#2, 4*#2, 5*#2, 6*#2, 7*#2, 8*#2, 9*#2, 10*#2, 11*#2, 12*#2, 13*#2},
          yminorgrids,
          xtick=data,
          ticklabel style = {font=\normalsize}, % Adjust font size here
          legend style={at={(0.05,0.95)},anchor=north west,cells={anchor=west},column sep=1ex},
          after end axis/.append code={
            \node[anchor=south east, xshift=-10pt, yshift=10pt] at (rel axis cs:1,0) {#3};
          }
        ]
        % Upper error bars
        \addplot+[blue, very thick, only marks, forget plot]
        plot[error bars/.cd, y dir=plus, y explicit]
        table[x=x,y=y,y error expr=\thisrow{y-max} - \thisrow{y}] {#1};
        % Lower error bars
        \addplot+[red, very thick, only marks, forget plot]
        plot[error bars/.cd, y dir=minus, y explicit]
        table[x=x,y=y,y error expr=\thisrow{y} - \thisrow{y-min}] {#1};
        % Main data points
        \addplot[only marks, mark=*, mark options={fill=blue, draw=red, very thick}]
        table[x=x,y=y] {#1};
        % Upper bound points
        \addplot[only marks, mark=square*, color=blue]
        table[x=x,y expr=\thisrow{y-max}] {#1};
        % Lower bound points
        \addplot[only marks, mark=square*, color=red]
        table[x=x,y expr=\thisrow{y-min}] {#1};
        % Add a dotted red line joining the averages
        \addplot [red, thick, dotted]
        table[x=x,y=y] {#1};
      \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

data3.csv
category,x,y,y-max,y-min
AR-0X1X,4,2.5,4.0,0.5
AR-0X1X,5,3.2,4.0,1.2
AR-0X1X,6,1.8,3.5,0.8
AR-0X1X,7,2.9,3.8,1.2
AR-0X1X,8,3.7,4.0,0.7
AR-0X1X,9,2.6,3.2,1.0
AR-0X1X,10,3.3,4.0,0.9
AR-0X1X,11,1.9,3.1,0.5
AR-0X1X,12,3.1,3.9,0.8
AR-0X1X,13,2.8,3.7,1.1
AR-0X1X,14,3.5,4.0,0.6
AP-0X1X,4,35.0,45.0,20.0
AP-0X1X,5,50.0,70.0,30.0
AP-0X1X,6,65.0,85.0,40.0
AP-0X1X,7,60.0,90.0,25.0
AP-0X1X,8,75.0,95.0,35.0
AP-0X1X,9,80.0,100.0,40.0
AP-0X1X,10,55.0,78.0,20.0
AP-0X1X,11,70.0,82.0,35.0
AP-0X1X,12,90.0,100.0,50.0
AP-0X1X,13,65.0,90.0,25.0
AP-0X1X,14,85.0,100.0,45.0


So I need to update either main.tex to load data filtered by category column

or, better still,

I need to update plot_template.tex so that first I load all data. Then, it filters by category column according to a parameter that I pass.

Do you know how I can do this?

Welcome. // From pgfplotstable: "If you want
to plot only selected table entries with \addplot table, use the pgfplots coordinate filter options." So see "4.22 Skipping Or Changing Coordinates – Filters" in pgfplots manual, e.g. here: https://tikz.dev/pgfplots/reference-coordfiltering. (Please note that your columns may be not what pgfplot expects ...) // However, applying a script beforehand on your data.csv seems to be more flexible to me. (PERL, PHP, grep, sed, ... you name it)

I will have many charts, and I want to avoid having too many CSVs.  The idea was that I load a single CSV and then filter it according to what I need.

Thank you. // I suggest to add these considerations to the beginning of your question: better in a prominent place, than burried in many comments ;-) New users have some limitations here for a while, so please notify my, if you want me to add it.

I added a sentence in the intro to the problem.

\begin{filecontents*}{data3.csv}
category,x,y,y-max,y-min
AR-0X1X,4,2.5,4.0,0.5
AR-0X1X,5,3.2,4.0,1.2
AR-0X1X,6,1.8,3.5,0.8
AR-0X1X,7,2.9,3.8,1.2
AR-0X1X,8,3.7,4.0,0.7
AR-0X2X,9,2.6,3.2,1.0
AR-0X2X,10,3.3,4.0,0.9
AR-0X2X,11,1.9,3.1,0.5
AR-0X2X,12,3.1,3.9,0.8
AR-0X2X,13,2.8,3.7,1.1
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{
discard if not/.style 2 args={
x filter/.code={
    \edef\tempa{\thisrow{#1}}
    \edef\tempb{#2}
    \ifx\tempa\tempb
    \else
        \def\pgfmathresult{nan}
    \fi
}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot[
red, only marks,
discard if not={category}{AR-0X1X},
] table[x=x, y=y, col sep=comma] {data3.csv};
\addplot[
green, only marks,
discard if not={category}{AR-0X2X},
] table[x=x, y=y, col sep=comma] {data3.csv};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


Code from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/58563/8650
